# Converting an If-Else statement into a Formula

Tags: java, algorithm, math

I have code as follows:

```
`if (a <= 10){
    z = 5;
 } else {
    z = -1;
 }`
```

I figured out that when `s(10 - a) = |10 - a| / (10 - a)` where it outputs a 1 or -1. It outputs `1` if `a < 10` and `-1` if `a > 10`.

Then, I just solve the linear equation `z = s(10 - a) * m + b`, to find constants m and b.

`5 = 1 * m + b`  and `-1 = -1 * m + b`
Which outputs `b = 2, m = 3`.

Then this can be modeled as `z = 3 * s(10 - a) + 2`.

Now the question becomes more tricky. What if I have two variables in nested if statements? Such as:

```
`if (a <= 10){
    if(b <= 3){
       z = 3;
    } else {
       z = 1;
    }
 } else {
    if(b <= -5){
       z = -11;
    } else {
     z = 4;
    }
}`
```

I tried to solve this using another series of linear equations.

1. `3 = A * s(10 - a) + B * s(3 - b) + C`
2. `1 = A * s(10 - a) + B * s(3 - b) + C`
3. `-11 = A * s(10 - a) + D * s(-5 - b) + C`
4. `4 = A * s(10 - a) + D * s(-5 - b) + C`

with A, B, C, D as constants. However, this isn't giving me the right answer. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What did you get if you solve the last linear equations

Comment: I got an equation of  z = (11/4) * s(10 - a) + s(3 - b) - (3/4) - (15/2) * s(-5 - b)

Comment: apache math may be a starting point (as a library if you need to solve LEs, as source code if you're curious how to implement a solution) - http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/linear.html

Comment: I solved it and get quite different answer...but before that, how can you write a single equation of z which includes A,B,C & D? Not good at math, but I feel like, this model may not be correct as  g(x) is dependent on f(x) where g(x) = s(b) and f(x) = s(a)?

Comment: @shole I think the model may not be correct, as you said. My strengths don't lie in Linear Algebra, and I'm a bit lost on how to approach it.

Comment: I might be stating the obvious here, but the first formula is not really equivalent to the if else statement because of division by 0 when a is 10.

Comment: @maraca You're right. This would be undefined at the breakpoints. But I can't find any other way to define it.

Comment: @maraca Yea...basically I would like to know is there really a math / logical basis which can convert such if-else statement to linear equation?  And assuming it CAN, I would think next obvious question: 1. What happens if there is else-if statement which divide number line to > 2 parts?  2. Like OP, nested if-else?   3. Mix of 1 & 2?      Are all these cases can be translated to linear equation system?

Comment: @shole I feel like something like this would work. z = A * s(10 - a) + (B * s(3-b) OR D * s(-5 - b)) + C where only one "b" function is used.

Comment: Mathematicians have an if statement, but I guess it would be cheating to write the formula like this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/611792/mathematical-if-else-statement, but this question is not really about the algorithm imho, so you might get more help from math exchange.

Comment: @maraca I looked at almost every question that was on the web, but I couldn't find much when there is nested statements. I'm really stuck.

Comment: @Steven Conditional Statment is sometimes used in maths equation as well, thus I think if you accept this you can just literally translate the code to equation. But if you insist using "pure" algebra, then is the OR acceptable in formulating the equation?...

Comment: @shole It isn't acceptable. It needs to be just an algebraic solution. Is there a way in math to declare a variable 0 if another variable is 1?

Comment: @Steven yea, you finally clear your mind and have a core question, let me think about it but this question should clearly be posted on math exchange now :)

Comment: @Steven Not sure if it is what you want,  y = f(x), which  when x = 1, y = 0 & x =0 , y = 1.   f(x) = (x-1)*(x-1)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An if statement can be transformed into a formula by using the following trick: we need to find a formula that's 1 if the `if` statement is true and 0 otherwise. We can use the signum function for this:

```
 f(x, y) = (sign(y - x) + 1) / 2
```

f(x, y) is 1 if x < y and 0 if x > y. The inverse g(x, y) = 1 - f(x, y).

So with those two formulas we can easily put together the whole thing:

```
f(a, 10) * (f(b, 3) * 3 + g(b, 3) * 1) + g(a, 10) * (f(b, -5) * -11 + g(b, -5) * 4)
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

A general equation of the form:

`((z2+z1)/2) + (|z2-z1|/2)*f(a,b)`

where `f(a,b) = |a-b|/(a-b)`

In english: 
`(midpoint between 2 given z values) + 
(distance from midpoint to either z value)*|a-b|/(a-b)`

trying this on the original example:

```java
if (a <= 10){
    z = 5;
 } else {
    z = -1;
 }
```

you get:

`z1=5` `z2=-1`

`f(a,b)=f(10,a)=|10-a|/(10-a)`

plugging these in...

`((5-1)/2) + (|5-(-1)|/2)*|10-a|/(10-a)`

simplifying to your original `z = 3 * s(10 - a) + 2`

When applying this to nested conditional:

```java
if (a <= 10) {
  ... // z1
} else {
  ... // z2
}
```

for `z1` i get `z1 = 2 + |3-b|/(3-b)`

for `z2` i get `-3.5 + 7.5*(|-5-b|/(-5-b))`. `z1` seems ok but `z2` doesn't seem to work since if you tried `b=0` you have `z2 = -3.5 - 7.5*(1)` but since `0>-5` you would expect `z2 = 4` since:

```java
if (b <= -5) {
  z = -11;
} else {
  z = 4;
}
```

to get the correct expression i swapped the definition of `f(a,b) = |a-b|/(a-b)` to `f(a,b) = |b-a|/(b-a)` the new result being `z2 = -3.5 + 7.5*(|b+5|/(b+5))` and testing `b=0` gives the correct result of `4`. This reduces the nested conditional to look like the simpler problem

```java
if (a <= 10) z =  2 + |3-b|/(3-b)

else z = -3.5 + 7.5*(|b+5|/(b+5))
```

which assuming you know `b` you can apply the same method above used for the simple case.

Comment: Thank you. I took the first answer that was posted, but this is also very helpful.